# How to use a .property file from git for a parametrized job choices

Tags: jenkins

I need to take from git repo a file (.properties) and use that file in a parametrized job choices to be selected by the user. any ideas? it only works with a file that exists on the same server but I need it from git repo to be chosen and put in choices.